# Is the Dutch translation incomplete?

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

Using kickstart 2-rc4 I seem to miss some Dutch translations (I used the 2.x translation file).

[image: screenshot]

If 'Add a product' ('Voeg een product toe') is translated, then why would 'Manage products' not be translated? The Dutch .po file does indeed not contain a translation for this, but it seems weird, if you would translate the one, why not translate the other?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try importing the translation file again; it is possible that the connection timed out and that some of the translations were not inserted.

However, if you check the `.po` file and you can't find the translations of those strings - it means that whoever was translating the terms did not finish them all.

You can translate missing terms yourself within Drupal at `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` or download [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) and [contribute translations](http://drupal.org/node/302194) back [here](http://localize.drupal.org/translate).

Comment: The .po file does not contain the missing translations, so a time out is not likely, also I would see a time out in my browser right? I am going to write translations if they really aren't available. But it seems rather strange that the one string is translated and the other not

Comment: It's then up to the person who did the translation. All translations are contributed just like the modules/themes, so noone can guarantee that everything will be done correctly/completely.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question. Yes a lot of translations are missing.

My installation language overview

Translate interface

```
Language    Built-in interface  Fields                 Drupal Commerce
Dutch       4834/9902 (48.82%)  4831/4988 (96.85%)     208/208 (100%)

Language    Built-in interface  Fields                 Drupal Commerce
Dutch   8647/12281 (70.41%) 4831/4996 (96.7%)      208/208 (100%)
```